# How to check if multiple keys exist in an EntityKind without also fetching the data at the same time?

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-datastore

I am using Cloud Firestore in Datastore mode. I have a list of keys of the same Kind, some exist already and some do not. For optimal performance, I want to run a compute-intensive operation only for the keys that do not yet exist. Using the Python client library, I know I can run [client.get_multi()](https://googleapis.dev/python/datastore/1.13.2/client.html) which will retrieve the list of keys that exist as needed. The problem is this will also return unneeded Entity data associated with existing keys, increasing the latency and cost of the request.

Is there a better way to check for existence of multiple keys?

Answer (score 0):

You could check whether a key exists using [keys-only queries](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/queries#keys-only_queries) as they return only the keys instead of the entities themselves, at lower latency and cost than retrieving entire entities.